# Buffer of char* in c++ using strlen bug

Tags: c++, char, c-strings, strncpy

i am trying to implement and + operator that gets rhs obj
and lhs obj,
the object contains char* string;
for for e.g
s1 contains "eden"
s2 contains "sh"
I want that s3 = s1 +s2 will be "eden sh" yet I cannot figure it out.
I don't USE vector or std::string because the assignment was to do char* arr
code:

```
auto *buff = new char[std::strlen(lhs.getName()) + std::strlen(rhs.getName()) + 2];
assert(buff);
std::strncpy(buff, lhs.getName(), std::strlen(lhs.getName()));
std::strncpy(buff + std::strlen(lhs.getName())," ", sizeof(char));
std::strncpy(buff + std::strlen(lhs.getName()), rhs.getName(), std::strlen(rhs.getName()));
tmp.setName(buff);
```

***set name is a function that copies buffer to m_name private data member.

the result is edensh

Answer (score 1):

If you compare these two records

```
std::strncpy(buff + std::strlen(lhs.getName())," ", sizeof(char));
std::strncpy(buff + std::strlen(lhs.getName()), rhs.getName(), std::strlen(rhs.getName()));
```

you will see that they both start write at position `buff + std::strlen(lhs.getName())`. So the second call of `strncpy` overwrites symbols of the previous call of `strncpy`.

Also there is another problem. The result array does not contain a string because the stored sequence of characters is not appended with the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Instead you could write for example

```
size_t n = std::strlen( lhs.getName() );

auto *buff = new char[n + std::strlen(rhs.getName()) + 2];
assert(buff);
std::strcpy( buff, lhs.getName() );
std::strcpy( buff + n, " " );
std::strcpy (buff + n + 1, rhs.getName() );
tmp.setName(buff);
```

Also instead of this call of the function `strcpy`

```
std::strcpy( buff + n, " " );
```

it is enough to write

```
buff[n] = ' ';
```

So you can also write

```
size_t n = std::strlen( lhs.getName() );

auto *buff = new char[n + std::strlen(rhs.getName()) + 2];
assert(buff);
std::strncpy( buff, lhs.getName(), n );
buff[n] = ' ';
std::strcpy (buff + n + 1, rhs.getName() );
tmp.setName(buff);
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad from Moscow i have fixed my code

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are forgetting to account for the " " char on the offset.

```
std::strncpy(buff + std::strlen(lhs.getName()) + 1, rhs.getName(), std::strlen(rhs.getName()));
```